# Should _escaped_fragment_ returns a full page contents [ Ajax SEO ]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, seo

Iam trying to understad the SEO with ajax ...
What I know is all my ajax links must be (pretty url) something with the format #!anything
So when the robots read my page and finds any of #! urls try to request the contents by using _escaped_fragment_ instead and this will be handled by my php file to return the contents ( right! ) but my question is should my php file that dealing with _escaped_fragment_ returns a full page or the contents only ?

Ex:
If I have a large html page with html, head, body elements and every thing with a section that contains ajax links #! when the user click on them retrive a contents such as ...... and put this div in this section .. should I return this div only to the robots or should I return the whole page (html, head, body ... etc ) with the changed contents too ?

Answer (score 1):

Full page.

The HTML returned from the page requested with `_escaped_fragment_` should be the same HTML in the DOM of the client once the page has finished loading the content at `#!`.  This includes `<head>`, `<body>` and everything else.  The crawler doesn't know or care where that inner content would appear.  It's up to your code to create that full page.

Comment: To complete the answer, the [Google's specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) makes reference only to page snapshots. And this is important for search engines to get the full page because they could analyse the content you provide in his real context without losing semantic informations.